# How to access view mode in an extender

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I would like to listen to a property called isDesktop and when it changes trigger show/hide options panel. Problem is within the extender the only parts I can access are target, option and this, none of which provide access to the view model where the show/hide methods are located.

This was working before I switched to using Require JS and components because it used the global scope to access these things. Nicer not to use the global scope but it does limit access to necessary properties. I've tried binding this but that only gives me access to the global window object which doesn't provide access.

```
  ko.extenders.responsive = function(target, option) {
    target.subscribe(function(isDesktop) {
      if (isDesktop) //showOptions()
      else //hideOptions()
    })
    return target
  }
//
  isDesktop: ko.observable(false).extend({ responsive: true }),
```

I presume there is a way to access the scope that called the extender from the extender. If not then what other solutions can be tried?

Comment: Instead of passing the value "true" for parameter "option", since that doesn't appear to be used anyways, pass a reference to your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Might this example help you on your way perhaps? I added the viewmodel but would debate if passing it along is really what you'd want?

```js
console.clear();

ko.extenders.responsive = function(valueAccessor, options) {
  valueAccessor.subscribe(function(value) {
    if (value)
     options.target(options.message);
    else
     options.target('');
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(() => {
 var self = this;
  self.desktopOptions = ko.observable('');
  self.isDesktop = ko.observable(false).extend({ responsive: { vm: self, target: self.desktopOptions, message: 'desktop is set' }});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDesktop" />
<span data-bind="text: desktopOptions"></span>
```